# Unable to mount Samsung Android

Tags: android, ubuntu-mate

Everytime I connect my android phone to my desktop, I get a popup saying

Unable to mount Samsung Android
Unable to open MTP device ..

Is there a way to stop those popups?

[image]

Comment: You can find a related question and its answers in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055304/unable-to-mount-samsung-android-on-ubuntu#15856509)